# Get tables row id by index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having some annoying trouble with this. I need to get the id of the row in my table, while searching by the index.

```
table_id=$(this).closest('table').attr('id'); //Table Id
```

I have the table id and for instance I need the second rows id. I have tried using the nth:child along with .children and other but everything I try comes back in an undefined result. I know its a simple fix but I can not seem to get it to work.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your markup? You might have a `tbody` tag so you need to adjust the selector accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty simple, given the id of the table select the `tr` and use `.eq` to find the row needed - remember that it will be zero based, so the second row would be `eq(1)`

```js
var table_id="myTable"
var secondRowId = $('#' + table_id + ' tr').eq(1).attr('id');
alert(secondRowId)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
    <tr id="row1">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I took a glimpse at this and realized what I was doing wrong. I forgot that it was 0 indexed so I was using eq(2) trying to get the second row. Ugh well thank you for your help!

Comment: @workingxx if it makes you feel any better i did the exact same thing and got `undefined` just like you :) Thats why I added the note.

Answer (score 0):

What selector have you tried with `nth-child`?

If it were me, here is the selector I would use to get the `ID` of the second row in your table:

```
var table_id = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
var t_selector = '#' + table_id + ' tr:nth-child(2)';
var row_id = $(t_selector).attr('id');
```